# Blender eevee emission shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, eevee-render-engine

[image: emission and no light source - blender 2.8 eevee]

[image: emission and a point light source -blender 2.8 eevee]

[image: Blender 2.7 with just emission shader on]

So still kinda new to blender, and decided to try out 2.8 because of eevee. But I seem to be doing something wrong. Was trying to figure out why the emission wasn't showing a shadow by itself on the two blocks like in the cycles preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add emission shader you have to do like this....
[image]

[image]

i hope this help you.